# Split list into sub-lists, similar to collate but with a max size of the result

Tags: groovy

Let's say I have a list

```
def letters = 'a' .. 'g'
```

I know that I can use collate to create a list of sub-lists of equal size (plus the remainder).

```
assert letters.collate(3) == [['a', 'b', 'c'], ['d', 'e', 'f'], ['g']]
```

But what I want is to get a list of a specific size of sub-lists, where the items of the original list are split into sublists that are as big as needed to get the most equal distribution of the sub-list size. Example:

```
def numbers = 1..7

assert numbers.collateIntoFixedSizedList(5) == [[1,2], [3,4], [5], [6], [7]]
// the elements that contain two items could be at the end of the list as well
// doesn't matter much to me
assert numbers.collateIntoFixedSizedList(5) == [[1], [2], [3], [4,5], [6,7]]
```

Lists that are smaller than the max_size would produce a list of the same size as the original of single element lists:

```
def numbers = 1..7
assert numbers.collateIntoFixedSizeList(10) == [[1],[2],[3],[4],[5],[6],[7]]
```

Does anybody know whether such magic exists or will I have to code this up myself?

Comment: close, but not `letters.collate( (letters.size()/5).trunc()+1 as Integer )`

Comment: if order not matter: `letters.indexed().groupBy{k,v-> k%5}.collect{k,v-> v.values()}`

Comment: @daggett order does matter.

Answer (score 3):

There's nothing built in to Groovy to do this, but you could write your own:

```
def fancyCollate(Collection collection, int groupCount) {
    collection.indexed().groupBy { i, v -> i % groupCount }.values()*.values()
}
```

Or, you could do this, which creates less intermediate objects:

```
def fancyCollate(Collection collection, int groupCount) {
    (0..<collection.size()).inject([[]] * groupCount) { l, v ->
        l[v % groupCount] += collection[v]
        l
    }
}
```

Try #2 ;-)

```
def fancyCollate(Collection collection, int size) {
    int stride = Math.ceil((double)collection.size() / size)
    (1..size).collect { [(it - 1) * stride, Math.min(it * stride, collection.size())] }
        .collect { a, b -> collection.subList(a, b) }
}

assert fancyCollate('a'..'z', 3) == ['a'..'i', 'j'..'r', 's'..'z']
```

Try #3 (with your example)

```
Collection.metaClass.collateIntoFixedSizeList = { int size ->
    int stride = Math.ceil((double)delegate.size() / size)
    (1..Math.min(size, delegate.size())).collect { [(it - 1) * stride, Math.min(it * stride, delegate.size())] }
        .collect { a, b -> delegate.subList(a, b) }
}

def numbers = (1..7)
assert numbers.collateIntoFixedSizeList(10) == [[1],[2],[3],[4],[5],[6],[7]]
```

Comment: Close but there are two problems. 1) it doesn't maintain order (I did not explain that was a requirement well enough in my question) and 2) when groupCount is larger than the input list, this creates a bunch of empty elements at the back of the output list. But thanks for the answer, it does get an upvote ;)

Comment: If at first, you don't succeed...  Edit your answer with another go 

Comment: Well... that fails for lists > max_size:

def numbers_larger = (1..15)
numbers_larger.collateIntoFixedSizeList(10)

This fails for me.

I've already implemented this myself by using a function. So I don't need an answer, but I just wanted to let you know that your solution still falls a bit short, in case you need a challenge and want to solve this properly ;)

Comment: Dagnabbit...  challenge accepted...  This is a tricky one indeed...  It feels like there's a simple solution hiding somewhere...  but it's currently avoiding me ;-)

Comment: hehe :) It is a bit of a nail biter.

I do have the code that works for me... rewritten to fit the simpler use case of just having an array of numbers.

You can see it here if you want, but it's much more verbose than what you're doing (I'm a Java programmer you see):
https://gist.github.com/StFS/c940ba02ccf2572d3fb107e78b1a7358

Feel free to take a look at it to maybe get some ideas, but as I said, it's not using any fancy Groovy stuff.